# Magento upgrade failed - Plugin initialization failed (require(../symfony/polyfill-php70/bootstrap.php)

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I was given a website to upgrade and while running the upgrade of Magento 2.31 to 2.37-p2 I ran into this error:

```
    Plugin initialization failed (require(/home/rainbow/public_html/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-php70/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory), uninstalling plugin
  - Removing magento/inventory-composer-installer (1.2.0)
    Update of magento/inventory-composer-installer failed


  [ErrorException]
  require(/home/rainbow/public_html/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-php70/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Apparently the site is missing something. How can I fix this and get this installed?

Thanks
Pete

Answer (score 0):

I had this same weird problem after upgrading from 2.4.2 to 2.4.3.
What I did to resolve this was:

(1) Remove dependency "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "^1.1" from composer.json

(2) Remove composer.lock file

(3) Remove vendor folder

(4) Run composer install